# Python structural pattern matching for string containing float

Tags: python, pattern-matching

How can I use structural pattern matching for the following use case:

```
values = ["done 0.0", "done 3.9", "failed system busy"]

for v in values:
   vms = v.split()
   match vms:
       case ['done', float()>0]: # Syntax error
           print("Well done")
       case ['done', float()==0]: # Syntax error
           print("It is okay")
       case ['failed', *rest]:
           print(v)
```

Please excuse me for the syntax errors, I have written this to demonstrate my thought process.

What could be the right syntax to achieve this pattern matching? Is it even possible?

Comment: Something similar can be spelled as `case ['done', float() as x] if x > 0:`, but it won't work here: `split` returns strings, not floats. What would you like to do with `"done foo"` string - raise TypeError or consider "failed"? To raise, `case ['done', x] if float(x) > 0`. To skip - get rid of `match/case` and use `if... try... except...`

Comment: You are trying to *produce* the kind of structure that the `match` statement is supposed to match. You'd want something like `vms = parse_message(v); match vms: case Done(v) if v > 0: ...; case Done(v) if v == 0: ...; case Failed(msg): print(msg)`, where `parse_message` returns instances of classes `Done` and `Failed` that you define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost got it. You missed referencing the second value.

```py
values = ['done 0.0', 'done 3.9', 'failed system busy']

for v in values:

   match v.split():
       case 'done', x if float(x) > 0:
           print('Well done')
       case 'done', x if float(x) == 0:
           print('It is okay')
       case 'failed', *rest:
           print(v)
```

Also, you may want to add a last case that catches the not covered ones:

```py
       case _:
           print('Any other case')
```

This is clearer and more concise than the `ìf-then-else-try-catch` alternative. Actually, `match` was created just for cases like this one. That's why it's called ***structural pattern** matching*.

Answer (score 1):

`if ...else` would be simpler but if you do want pattern matching then you have a number of issues to be resolved. Your string does not contain a float, it contains a string of characters which *could* be converted to a float.  So to test value of a float you have to test that it IS a float in string form and then convert to a float then test. The 'wildcard' character is `_` which should be used to capture non-matching elements with *_ to catch any number of other elements. The following code does what I think you want and could be the basis for further development. Firstly Regex is used to test for the float with a 'guard' expression in the pattern. The Regex would pick up error entries such as "3.x".

```
import re
values = ["done 0.0", "done 3.9", "failed system busy"]

for v in values:
    vms = v.split()
 
    match vms:
        case ['done', x] if x == '0.0': print(vms, 'It is OK')
        case ['done', x] if re.match(r'\d+.\d+', x) and float(x) > 3.0: print(vms, 'Well done')
        case ['failed', *_]: print(v)
        case _: print('unknown case')
```

produces:

```
['done', '0.0'] It is OK
['done', '3.9'] Well done
failed system busy
```

Another way, without Regex, would be to write a checking function such as:

```
def check_float(f):
    f = f.strip()
    try:
        _ = float(f)
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

and then the case would be:

```
case ['done', x] if check_float(x) and float(x) > 3.0: print(vms, 'Well done')
```